# Download and Read the file using Cypress Typescript

Tags: typescript, pdf, cypress

I am trying to download a PDF file by clicking on a element and validating the document has expected data using cypress typescript, i have used following code:

[https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/cypress/file-download-testing][1]

i get error when trying cy.downloadFile as `Property 'downloadFile' does not exist on type 'cy & EventEmitter'`

Can someone help me how do I download and read the file

Answer (score 0):

In **tsconfig.json**

Add **cypress-downloadfile** to the **types** array:

```
"types": ["cypress","cypress-downloadfile"], /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */
```